# Cannot use method getTotalLength() on path that is dynamically created

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I was trying to work with SVGs and came across this issue. I am unable to use the SVGGeometryElement on any Path object I create through Javascript. I get the error .getTotalLength is not a method when trying to call it on the path Node or Element (after I added it to the body. If anyone has any insight it would be greatly appreciated. The Code Pen includes an SVG that is included in the HTML and it works as expected.

Code pen: https://codepen.io/Jordan-the-builder/pen/OJazGpe

I tried adding the SVG element to the body, adding the namespace, and updating the reference to the path after adding it to the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="svg1">SVG with id "test" has a length of </p>
        <svg>
          <path id="test" d="M10 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 Z"></path>
        </svg>
        
        <p id="svg2">SVG generated has a length of </p>
        <div id="generated-svg">
        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
let svg1 = document.getElementById("svg1");
let path1 = document.getElementById("test");
svg1.innerHTML = svg1.innerHTML + path1.getTotalLength();

let svgNode = document.createElement("svg");
            svgNode.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");

let pathNode = document.createElement("path");
svgNode.appendChild(pathNode);
pathNode.setAttribute("d", "M10 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 Z");

document.getElementById("generated-svg").appendChild(svgNode);
            
try {
console.log("path Length: " + pathNode.getTotalLength());
  
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  let svg2 = document.getElementById("svg2");
  svg2.innerHTML = svg2.innerHTML + " .getTotalLength() is not a method :/";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`document.createElementNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) instead of [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to make the `<svg>` and `<path>` elements.

```js
let svgNode = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
let pathNode = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
// now calling pathNode.getTotalLength() works
```

Comment: Or append the path as HTML ``svg.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<path d="M10 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 Z"/>' )`` Then the browser will set the correct NameSpace. Its also faster than ``append``: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/11738/0/insertadjacenthtml-vs-append#latest_results_block